# Custom Spinner with default down arrow in it

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have a custom layout for spinner. Its both selected and dropdown list item's background color will change depending on user demand. So i am changing depending on  their values.. so far so good. But the problem is since i am using custom layout or changing background color, there is no arrow to show that it is a spinner. When i add arrow from layout then all even dropdown list have that arrow with them. I can manipulate it by setting arrow's background to null for drop down items but it is not a good way and dont always work. So how can i show spinner default arrow with my custom spinner without using spinner style. **Dont forget that i am changing background of every item.**

Here is my custom_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="6" android:id="@+id/spinnerMainLayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="14"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="New Text" android:textSize="19sp" android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/type" android:typeface="serif"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"  android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="#666666" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_weight="9"
    android:typeface="serif" android:maxLines="3" android:minLines="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="sd" android:textSize="18sp" android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/history" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my custom spinner class

```
class CustomSpinner extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

    private String[] fixStrs = new String[]{"Definition","Result","Error"};

    public CustomSpinner(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        //fixStrs = objects;
    }

    @Override public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    @Override public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

        /*LinearLayout spinnerMain = (LinearLayout) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMainLayout);
        spinnerMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[0]));*/

        TextView fixText = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.type);
        fixText.setText(fixStrs[position]);
        fixText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));

        TextView historyText = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.history);
        historyText.setText(history[position]);
        historyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));

        return mySpinner;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you more specific pls?

Answer (score 0):

Create a different layout for the spinner dropdown and pass it to the [.setDropDownViewResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource(int)) method of the ArrayAdapter, then you must specify the id of the textview in this layout in the constructor call of your adapter